# Converting a List<MyObject> into a Map<Integer, String> based on the Max MyObject property in Java 8

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I have a `List<MyObject>`. It contains multiple records for one `objectId`.

`MyObject` class looks like

```
class MyObject{
  int id;
  int objectId;
  String status;
  LocalDate updatedTimestamp;
}
```

I need a `Map<Integer, String>` with `objectId` as *Key* and corresponding `status` as a *Value*.

I need to consider only the record for one `objectId` with latest `updatedTimestamp`.

Different timestamps will have different `status`. Need only the latest one.

I didn't find a way of achieving this. I know I can get `Map<integer, Optional<MyObject>>` by applying `groupingBy()` and `maxBy()`.

Please advise.

Comment: Did you have any attempt?

Comment: Couldn't find anything to achieve this. I could either get Map<integer, Optional<MyObject>> by doing groupBy ans maxBy on it.

Comment: @jasmeet It would be match better if you would share the code you've tried, even if it was not successful (*there would be no need for you in posting the question if you had a code that you're satisfied with*). The question should demonstrate effort, that why it's always better to show your attempt to approach the problem. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using collector `groupingBy()` in conjunction with `collectingAndThen()` and `maxBy()`.

Collector `maxBy()` expect a *comparator* as an argument and produces an optional result. To create a comparator, we can make use of the Java 8 method [`Comparator.comparing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function,java.util.Comparator)).

```
List<MyObject> objects = // initializing the source list.
        
Map<Integer, String> statusByObjectId = objects.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        MyObject::getObjectId,
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getUpdatedTimestamp)),
            (Optional<MyObject> result) -> result.orElseThrow().getStatus())
        ));
```